# Windows 8 will not restart if your Registry Hives are larger than 2GB. Why?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, reboot

Recently I read an article and in this article it mentions that if you are running 64-bit  Windows 8 it will not restart if your Registry Hives are larger than 2GB.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Ehm.. What's the error?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: What have you been doing that your registry has grown so large?

Comment: @nEwGUy - If you do the following I will upvote this question.  1) Link to the specific article you read.  2) Quote the article with the relevant statement. 3)  Don't ask the reason this is the case, just ask how to resolve the problem, we can't tell you "why" beyond its a known issue.  I would do all this myself, but I don't have the article, so I can't.

Comment: Looks like they might still be using 32-bit support apps for the registry thus the limit.

Comment: @mdpc - Except the memory limits for 32-bit applications in a 64-bit operating system is 4GB.

Comment: @Ramhound- the article name is "thewindowsclub",in this article i can't understand why will not restart?

Answer (score 4):

It is a known issue in **64-bit Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012**

Source: [Your Windows 8 will not restart if your Registry Hives are larger than 2GB. Why?](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-will-not-restart-registry-hives-2gb)

> The Windows Registry is a directory which stores settings and options
>   for the operating system for Microsoft Windows. It contains
>   information and settings for all the hardware, operating system
>   software, most non-operating system software, users, preferences of
>   the PC, and so on. A Registry Hive is a logical group of keys,
>   subkeys, and values in the registry that has a set of supporting files
>   containing backups of its data and are located in the \system32\,
>   \winnt\, etc locations.
>
> If you are running 64-bit Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012, and the
>   size of your Windows Registry Hives are larger than 2 GB in size, your
>   computer just will not restart.
>
> This is because the registry hives in x64-based version of Windows
>   have a 2 GB size limit, and if the size exceeds this limit, the system
>   is unable to restart.
>
> Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem and a known issue.
>
> If you are experiencing this particular issue, then you can download
>   Hotfix 496812 via [KB2978366](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2978366)

Comment: I would like to add though that neither that article or Microsoft do explain thoroughly why that happens. For the time being, I don't see a relation between the size limit and the inability to restart.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - I am going to upvote this answer.  I thought this patch was just released, I now see, the article was simply last revised this month.  This issue does not appear to effect Windows 8.1